# error System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Tags: c#

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // declarar variables
            string dato = "";

            int cantPesos = 0;
            int tasaCambio = 0;
            int cantDolares = 0;
            //pedir cantidad de pesos
            Console.WriteLine("Dame la cantidad de pesos");
            dato = Console.ReadLine();
            cantPesos = Convert.ToInt32(dato);
            // pedir cuantos pesos en 1 dolar

            Console.WriteLine("cuantos pesos hay en un dolar");
            dato = Console.ReadLine();
            tasaCambio = Convert.ToInt32(dato);

            // hacer la conversion
            cantDolares = cantPesos / tasaCambio;

            // mostrar resultados
        Console.WriteLine("{0) pesos son {1} dolares", cantPesos, cantDolares);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What input is throwing you off? What have you typed for the input in the console? Also, what's the exact line that the program is crashing at?

Comment: it crashes here  >>  Console.WriteLine("{0) pesos son {1} dolares", cantPesos, cantDolares);

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. To give us the best chance of helping you solve you issues we need as much information as possible. Including you code is a great start, but we also need a somewhat detailed explanation of what you error is and what lines you encounter exceptions.

Comment: just copy paste in visual studio as c# code and watch the error !

Answer (score 0):

You have made a slightly silly mistake, and this question could be closed by just typographic mistake, but here's the fix.

In the line `Console.WriteLine("{0) pesos son {1} dolares", cantPesos, cantDolares);` you have a closing parenthesis instead of the closing curly brace.

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // declarar variables
            string dato = "";

            int cantPesos = 0;
            int tasaCambio = 0;
            int cantDolares = 0;
            //pedir cantidad de pesos
            Console.WriteLine("Dame la cantidad de pesos");
            dato = Console.ReadLine();
            cantPesos = Convert.ToInt32(dato);
            // pedir cuantos pesos en 1 dolar

            Console.WriteLine("cuantos pesos hay en un dolar");
            dato = Console.ReadLine();
            tasaCambio = Convert.ToInt32(dato);

            // hacer la conversion
            cantDolares = cantPesos / tasaCambio;

            // mostrar resultados
        Console.WriteLine("{0} pesos son {1} dolares", cantPesos, cantDolares);
        }
    }
}
```